# how can we use prepareStatement()?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I use prepareStatement() when the id is a key of my SQL table and it will be created by SQL and I want to use this statement :(what should I write instead of X in the first column of SQL table(reminder:SQL create it automatically)

```
File file = new File(pathFile);
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);


            query = ("insert into birthtable VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            pstmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setInt(1,**X** )
            pstmt.setString(2, name);
            pstmt.setString(3, family);
            pstmt.setString(4, fatherName);
            pstmt.setString(5, mName);
            pstmt.setString(6, dOfBirth);
            pstmt.setString(7, pOfBirth);
            // Method used to insert a stream of bytes
            pstmt.setBinaryStream(8, input);




            pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

I have done what you all say
but I have this exception??

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2019)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1937)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1922)
    at database.Manager.addBirth(Manager.java:76)
    at AdminGUI.AddNewBornInformation.submit(AddNewBornInformation.java:358)
    at AdminGUI.AddNewBornInformation.setButtonActionPerformed(AddNewBornInformation.java:282)
    at AdminGUI.AddNewBornInformation.access$800(AddNewBornInformation.java:28)
    at AdminGUI.AddNewBornInformation$9.actionPerformed(AddNewBornInformation.java:139)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3265)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
```

Comment: You shouldn't do `(PreparedStatement)` cast.

Comment: I did not ,NetBeans did it for me!!!!?

Comment: But you still reserve the right to say no.

Comment: Exception: With the explicitly named columns? What's the SQL?

Comment: @Johanna with regards to you latest exception, check you have: 7 column names, 7 ?'s and 7 sets, that's really all there is to it beyond what everyone has already suggested.

Comment: You don't need to put that much exclamation marks or question marks in comments. Otherwise you overcome offensive. One (or none) is enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have specified the type of that column as int and auto-increment e.g.

```
`ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

then you don't need to supply any value at all, so you can start the prepared statement params at 1 with name.

```
 query = ("insert into birthtable (nameCol, familyCol, fatherNameCol, mNameCol, dOfBirthCol, pOfBirthCol, inputCol) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        pstmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pstmt.setString(1, name);
        pstmt.setString(2, family);
        pstmt.setString(3, fatherName);
        pstmt.setString(4, mName);
        pstmt.setString(5, dOfBirth);
        pstmt.setString(6, pOfBirth);
        // Method used to insert a stream of bytes
        pstmt.setBinaryStream(7, input);
```

Note that, as others have said, you must include the column names, whatever they might be.

Comment: we have 8 question marks ,and then I start with 1,so where is the value of eight question mark???

Comment: you need to remove one  - so there will only be seven

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify it yourself, so you can just leave it away. But you should however specify the columns yourself, e.g.

```
"INSERT INTO tablename (columnname1, columnname2, columnname3) VALUES (?, ?, ?);"
```

otherwise the DB wouldn't know where to insert the values because there is one column missing.

Answer (score 0):

You do not set the id parameter in the prepared statement assuming you're using auto increment and the column names are valid:

```
query = ("insert into birthtable (name, family, fatherName, mName, dOfBirth, pOfBirth, input) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setString(1, name);
pstmt.setString(2, family);
pstmt.setString(3, fatherName);
pstmt.setString(4, mName);
pstmt.setString(5, dOfBirth);
pstmt.setString(6, pOfBirth);
pstmt.setBinaryStream(7, input);
```

You should state the column names explicitly otherwise you depend on the order in the table create statement.

Answer (score -1):

My only 2 cents is that if you want a generated ID, you may call

```
pstmt.getGeneratedKeys( );
```

If it's going to return anything valid depends on your JDBC driver implementation though.